# Script Autocad offset and reduce vertices

Tags: autocad

Can anyone help me? 
I want to create a script to run in AutoCAD, that automatically makes OFFSET=100 of all LWPOLYLINE / AREA and delete the original and of this new offset reduce the vertices of all.

Tanks,

Select objects:

```
              LWPOLYLINE  Layer: ""
                        Space: Model space
               Handle = 412
        Closed
Constant width    0.0000
          area: please use AREA command for huge polylines
     perimeter   47713.9844
```

Comment: What exactly did you try, what did you expect, and how did it fail?